# I can't find where I put my startup script?

Tags: boot

Need help with a senior moment.

Using a headless Pi Zero and Jessie.  I have a Python script that is starting on boot or logon, but for the life of me I can't remember where I set it up.

It's not in /etc/rc.local, it's not in /etc/profile, and it isn't in crontab or /home/pi/.bashrc.  Not in init.d and definitely not through systemd.

Where else could I look?

Comment: Do you remember what you named it?

Answer (score 1):

Another possibility is that it's being started by `cron` or `anacron`. That could be starting it very shortly after boot.

The first step is to figure out if it's starting at or near boot or when you log in. The easiest way to check that is probably to create a second user account, disable automatic login, reboot your system, and log in to the second account to see if the script is running.

If it is running on login, check not only your `.bashrc` but also your `.profile` and your `.bash_profile`, and `/etc/bash.bashrc` and similar files. If those don't start it, it could be started by something related to your X session; the simple way to check this is to do a non-graphical login, either by starting your Pi in console mode or by ssh'ing in from your second account (after a reboot and having confirmed that it's not running before you log in to your `pi` account).

If it is being started on boot I might start by creating a systemd unit that checks whether or not the script is running and records that, and then move that unit around in the dependency graph to narrow down where it's starting.

Answer (score 1):

Just search for any file containing your script name:

```
grep -r "myscript.py" /etc /home /usr /var
```

If you don't remember the script's name, first search for keywords which would help you locate the script itself (messages it prints, commands it runs, names of files it creates, etc.)

If your script runs for a long time, a faster solution could be to print the process tree with `ps afx`, locate your script (or Python, if it's the only Python script running) in it, find its parent and deduce which configuration file could be involved. It's only faster if you know Linux well enough though.

Answer (score 0):

omg..I felt your pain, I ran a few frustrating hours trying to locate a startup item I put in the most unlikely of places (well after finding it I realised that I don't know why i didn't actually look there in the first place..lol)

What actually helped to locate it was running through the terminal history as far back as I could, to jog memory and lo and behold I found a reference to a directory from where the application was being called /home/pi/.config/autostart

Hope this simple tip will help someone else and spare them the frustration and hair pulling..